# How can I keep contact auto-completion from being deleted in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, autocomplete

In Outlook 2010, for some reason unknown to me, the auto-complete list for contacts gets cleared every time I restart Outlook.  I am referring to the auto-completion of recently used contacts when I send an e-mail.

Is there any setting that controls whether or not this list is cleared?